# how to view printf statements in rpl-ofc.c?

Tags: c, contiki

How can I show the `printf` statements in `rpl-of0.c` in the mote output window like the way we can see the `printf` statements in `rpl-icmp6.c`? I have tried `DEBUG_PRINT` and `DEBUG_FULL` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace 
`#define DEBUG DEBUG_NONE`
with 
`#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT`

Answer (score 0):

Change `DEBUG_NONE` to `DEBUG_PRINT`.